# Remove underline link on hover

Tags: html, css

I am trying to remove my underline on hover and everything, but it doesnt seem to be working.

`<a href="agent_user_add.php"><font face="verdana" class="pluslink" style="font-size:26px;">+</font></a>`

Below is my styling

`.pluslink a:link {text-decoration:none;}
.pluslink a:visited {text-decoration:none;}
.pluslink a:hover {text-decoration:none;}
.pluslink a:active {text-decoration:none;}`

How come its not working? Am i putting the class in the wrong place?

Here is a jsfiddle below!

[jSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nY5KB/)

Comment: @Musa I don't know if the Q was edited but there's one

Comment: I guess I missed that.

Comment: you should update your code; this is not a best approach. Better make a class and define the font property there and then call the class inside `<a>` tag.

Comment: A simple thing remove `<font face="verdana" class="pluslink" style="font-size:26px;">` and its closing tag. Apply `class="pluslink"` to the `<a>`. The `<font>` tag is oldschool and depreciated ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
.pluslink, .pluslink:visited,.pluslink:hover,.pluslink:active {
   text-decoration:none;
 }
<a href="agent_user_add.php" class="pluslink">+</a>
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/3pTTR/

**fiddle updated**

Comment: Did you see the fiddle

Comment: Font size needs to be added to the class in the CSS to replicate what the question had.

Answer (score 4):

Add:

```
a.pluslink {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nY5KB/8/)

Comment: The class name also needs to be moved from the font tag to the a tag if this is to work.

Answer (score 3):

Your styles are missing their target, as there is no `a` inside an element called `pluslink`. If you want to target this `a` specifically, you'll have to give it a class or target it through its parent element(s).

As an aside, `<font>` is from the 1990s and way out of date. Instead, target the `a` and set the fonts via CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Manish Jangir's answer will work, or if you prefer more specific styles, you can go with:

```
a .pluslink {text-decoration:none;}
a .pluslink:visited {text-decoration:none;}
a .pluslink:hover {text-decoration:none;}
a .pluslink:active {text-decoration:none;}
```

Comment: The a.plus link CSS will only apply to a tags with a class of pluslink. The original question has the pluslink class applied to the font tag inside of the a tag, thus that CSS will not apply to the a tag. The font tag will inherit the text-decoration property from it's parent, in this case the a tag.

Comment: Thanks nathangiesbrecht, edited my solution above :) I missed it the last time.

Answer (score 0):

The `font` tag by default inherits it's text-decoration property from it's parent. In this case, you have the `font` tag wrapped in an `a` tag, which is defaults to `text-decoration: underline`.

The CSS that you have is applied to `a` tags that are decedents of elements with a class of *pluslink*. In your case, the *pluslink* class is applied to the font tag, which is the child of the `a` tag. The opposite of the CSS you're going for.

The easiest solution would be for you to move your `font` tag outside of your `a` tag:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nY5KB/12/)

Alternatively, you could apply the *pluslink* class to your `a` tag, and edit your CSS code to include the font-size and font-family. The `font` tag has been deprecated for some time now. This also makes your code more manageable.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nY5KB/13/)